# rotate two canvases around their center

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, rotation, html5-canvas

I'm developing web app where is draggable panorama and image. User is able to drag image over panorama's edge. In this case I'm calculating value that represents part of the image that is out of panorama. Because of this value I can place another image on the other side of panorama ( panorama is 360° ) with width of this value.
Image is rotateable with mouse right click, when image is not over edge ( there is just 1 image in panorama ) it rotates well. But when I have 2 images ( image is dragged over edge ) one rotates nicely but the second one rotates very bad ( travelling around panorama ).
 Rotation when there is one image:

```
img_canvas.width = 150;
img_canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0,0,img_canvas.width, img_canvas.height);
img_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0,0, 150, 150);
main_ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
main_ctx.drawImage(bg_canvas, panoramaX,panoramaY,bg_canvas.width,bg_canvas.height);
main_ctx.translate(imageX+img_canvas.width/2, imageY+img_canvas.height/2);
main_ctx.rotate(angle);
main_ctx.translate(-(imageX+img_canvas.width/2),-(imageY+img_canvas.height/2));
main_ctx.drawImage(img_canvas, imageX, imageY);
main_ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
```

Rotation of two images:

```
var img_canvas_width = 150 - over_value;
img_canvas.width = img_canvas_width;
img_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage( img, 0, 0, 150, 150 );
img_canvas_split.width = over_value;
img_canvas_split.getContext('2d').drawImage( img_split, -img_canvas_width, 0, 150, 150 );
main_ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
main_ctx.drawImage( bg_canvas, panoramaX, panoramaY, bg_canvas.width, bg_canvas.height );
main_ctx.translate( imageX_hit + (img_canvas_width)/2, imageY + img_canvas.height/2 );
main_ctx.rotate( angle );
main_ctx.translate( -( imageX_hit + (img_canvas_width)/2), -(imageY + img_canvas.height/2) );
main_ctx.drawImage( img_canvas, imageX_hit, imageY );
main_ctx.translate( (bg_canvas.width - img_canvas_width/2 - over_value/2), imageY + img_canvas.height/2 );
main_ctx.translate( - (bg_canvas.width - img_canvas_width/2 - over_value/2), -(imageY + img_canvas.height/2) );
main_ctx.drawImage( img_canvas_split, panoramaX, imageY );
main_ctx.setTransform( 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 );
```

There is a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bimbochobot/nenb32f6/10/) with my problem.
Please, is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are not rotating the image per se but the transform. That transform matrix applies to all subsequent draw calls. You need to reset the transform between the two calls. But this will not help you much. I noticed that the clipping comes into view, too. So you should try this:

- transform 1
- draw 1 without clipping
- transform 2
- draw 2 without clipping

The actual clipping will be done by the canvas itself. I hope this helps.